# Google Places Autocomplete Not Working, Receiving error that my function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, next.js, autocomplete

I am building a form that takes in a user's city and province and want to use the Google Places Autocomplete feature. No matter what, I seem to be encountering errors.

I have added the following script into my code:

```
<Script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=$MY_KEY&loading=async&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer/>
```

Then I added the following function into the component where the autocomplete will be used:

```
function initAutocomplete () {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById("city-and-province"),
            {
                types: ['establishment'],
                componentRestrictions: {'country': ['ca']},
                fields: ['place_id', 'geometry', 'name']
            }
        ) 
    }
```

I keep getting this error:

> initAutocomplete is not a function.

If I remove the callback from the script, or if I try and create a `useEffect` instead of using a function, I get the error "google is undefined".

I am so confused. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Read the docs maybe? On how to load the API? Have you tried that?

Comment: I literally followed the docs word for word. They specify that if you are trying to load autocomplete without using having a visible map, you need to run this script in your code. the script isn't working although it's written exactly as google's docs said to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my end.

→ [Loading the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api)
→ [Adding an Autocomplete widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#add-autocomplete)

```js
function initMap() {
  const input = document.getElementById("city-and-province");
  const options = {
    types: ['establishment'],
  componentRestrictions: {
    'country': ['ca']
  },
  fields: ['place_id', 'geometry', 'name']
  };
  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="city-and-province">

<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&loading=async&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```